# How to retrieve a settings.py variable in a Django view

Tags: python, django

I followed the documentation which says to do this:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Do something
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

```
attributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'
```

Any idea? Thx.

Comment: You probably have some `settings` in the context other than `django.conf.settings` that points to a `function`.

Comment: Works for me. Can you check if there is no method named `settings` in the file you are making this `if settings.DEBUG:` check. Also make sure the intended settings file is being loaded by Django when you do a `runserver`

Comment: If you have conflicting settings, you can do `from django.conf import settings as DJANGOSETTINGS`, that should do it.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be a context problem since it now works (but I did nothing special). Thx.